# О visual studio community

Tags: windows, visual-studio

На выбор есть несколько сборок visual studio. Это enterprise, professional и community. Написано что community для проектов с открытым исходным кодом и всё такое. Это что получается, что я в community не могу делать коммерческие программы и игры?

Comment: Можешь делать коммерческие предложение. Разница в том что у платных есть дополнительные возможности для программирования

Comment: Сможешь, разве что функционал поменьше будет , не считая того что если ты захочешь продавать продукцию то тут уже нужно будет отдавать деньги в копилку студии

Comment: Не спрашивайте здесь о юридических вопросах, а то насоветуют непонятно что. Прочитайте сами лицензию и сделайте выводы: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/license-terms/mlt553321/

Comment: По моему, комьюнити вполне себе позволяет коммерческое использование индивидуальным разработчикам и микрофирмам с штатом до 5-ти человек

Comment: Зачем сообщать что сделано в visual studiи какой бы то ни было редакции? Говорите что работаете исключительно в блокноте и в cmd:) Конечному потребителю все равно же.

Comment: и собирать gcc/clang :) по теме, в бинарниках студия оставляет "свою отметку"  :)

Comment: @Sergey  короч лучше работать в code::blocks!